# Biexponential Model in R

Tags: r, regression, simulation, non-linear-regression

I have a question: In R for Biexponential Model can I use a data that contains negatives ??? Because it gives me ERROR !!! Is it possible that the negative numbers be the reason for that Errors ?

My function for Biexponential in R is:

`A1*exp(-exp(lrc1)*input)+A2*exp(-exp(lrc2)*input)`

Where:

- **input** - a numeric vector of values at which to evaluate the model.
- **A1** - a numeric parameter representing the multiplier of the first exponential.
- **lrc1** - a numeric parameter representing the natural logarithm of the rate constant of the first exponential.
- **A2** - a numeric parameter representing the multiplier of the second exponential.
- **lrc2** - a numeric parameter representing the natural logarithm of the rate constant of the second exponential.

Comment: Can you please give example data that is causing an issue.  Also, the error you are seeing would also be helpful.

Comment: input= 
  1.82554293
 -1.15465570  
  1.92298028 
 -2.03517932  
  0.27720635  
  0.11260995
  2.30357616
 -1.26658578 
 -0.36235703  
  0.34116112 
 -1.64166322 
 -0.04066538
  1.44557817 
 -0.17174340 
 -0.65744887  
  0.83922746 
 -0.79291094  
  0.16717272
 -0.63189164  
  0.85783800

Comment: the input is the data that i have @steveb

Comment: 'fm1 <- nls(SSbiexp(input, A1, lrc1, A2, lrc2), data = data.frame)

Error in SSbiexp(input, A1, lrc1, A2, lrc2) : object 'lrc1' not found

> fm1 <- nls(SSbiexp(input, A1, lrc1, A2, lrc2), data = input)

Error in SSbiexp(input, A1, lrc1, A2, lrc2) : object 'lrc1' not found
'

Comment: Your first issue is that `lrc1` is not defined.  The other issue you may run into is that the exponentials will sometimes return `Inf`.

Comment: Ok, but what do you mean by 'Inf' ??? @steveb

Comment: I mean infinity.  If you type `1/0` in `R`, you will get `Inf` back (`-1/0` gives `-Inf`).  `1/<a very small non-zero number>` will also give `Inf`

Comment: Ok, Thank you so much it was really helpful @steveb